# Evaluate the line integral $\oint_C \frac{z+1}{z^3-2z^2} dz$ along the given curves

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, line-integrals

Curve 1: $|z|=1$

Curve 2: $|z-2-i|=2$

So I figured out how to solve the first curve using Cauchy's Integral Formula. My answer matched the given one,$-\frac{3}{2}\pi i$, so we are good. However, the answer to the 2nd problem is $\frac{3}{2}\pi i$. This leaves me with the question: what difference does the curve make in using the formula that would remove the negative sign?

For reference, this is the formula I used:

$$\oint_C \frac{f(z)dz}{(z-z_0)^n} = \frac{2\pi i}{(n-1)!}f^{n-1}(z_0)$$

---

Thinking about it some more, I feel as though it has everything to do with the $z_0$ in the formula. Given curve 2, $z=2$ and $z=0$ both lie outside it. If this is the case, then what should I use in the formula for $z_0$?

Comment: For one, the loop around which you may integrate may contain a different pole, for example, the pole at $z=2$ is included in the second loop, but not in the first

Comment: @vnd Ah, I see where I made my mistake. I drew my picture wrong. I interpreted $|z-2-i|$ as $|z-(2-i)|$ instead of $|z-(2+i)|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $|z|<1$:

$z=0$ is singular point so we will define $f$ wit

$$\oint_C \frac{z+1}{z^3-2z^2} dz=\oint_C \frac{z+1}{z^2(z-2)} dz$$

Let $f(z):=\frac{z+1}{(z-2)} $

and $f'(z)=-\frac{3}{(z-2)^2}$

so the answer for the first $2\pi i \cdot f'(0)=-\frac{3\pi i}{2}$

---

For $|z-2-i|=2:$

The singular point is $z=2$

So let $g(z):=\frac{z+1}{z^2}$ so the answer $2\pi i \cdot g(2)=\frac{3\pi i}{2}$

Comment: Very clear answer, thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Write your integral as 
$$
\oint_C \frac{g(z)}{z - 2} dz
$$
for a suitable function $g$ and take it from there. Drawing the curve and the two poles of the function in the complex plane will also help clarify things.

Comment: If the 2 poles do not lie inside the curve, can I conclude that the integral $=0$?

Comment: You got it, that's Cauchy's Integral Theorem.

Comment: Ohhhh...wow I get it now! Thanks!